# Send stored integers to method?

Tags: java, netbeans

does anyone know any way to send integers to a method?
I'm struggling to send the generated integers in the main class to the method, can anyone help?
I'm trying to get the num1 to n1 and num2 to n2
Thanks

```
public class CompareNumbers {
static void CompareNums(){
    int n1 = num1;
    int n2 = num1;
    if ( n1 == n2)
    {
        System.out.print("The numbers are equal");
    }
    else if ( n1 > n2)
    {
        System.out.print("The first number is greater");
    }
    else if ( n2 > n1)
    {
        System.out.print("The second number is greater");
    }}public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompareNums();
    int max = 100;
    int min = 1; 
    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        int num1 =(int) (Math.random() * (max-min=1) + min); 
        int num2 = (int) (Math.random()* (max-min=1)+ min);
    }
    
    
    
}
```

}

Comment: Methods can take parameters. Well, your `CompareNums()` method can't because it's not defined to do so, you'll have to change its signature. Read a tutorial on the basics of Java, this is explained in every single one. Here's a good one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 0):

Your can use public static variables to call the number from main function

```html
public class Main{
  public static int num1;
  public static int num2;
}
```

Use Main.num1 to recall the number